# Boost Graph Library graph generation function issues

Tags: c++, boost, graph-theory

Ive been attempting to learn some graph theory for a personal project. I'm also trying to use the Boost Graph Library to perform these tasks.
The function below is an attempt to generate spanning tree graphs using the provided random_spanning_tree function and then connect parts of them randomly, but I cannot get the provided function to return the predecessor map in a working way.

Currently I declare the predecessor map and pass it into the random_spanning_tree function. the output is not what I am expecting. Using gdb, I can determine that the data structure is just that of the simply connected line graph the make_connected function builds, as well as large number which is what im assuming all of my data is being saved into in the 0th cell. I have included an image of the debug output for clarity. Clearly I am either not initializing or passing in the predecessor map correctly as all of my data is being saved into the first cell. Does anyone have any idea where I am going wrong?
Any help is greatly appreciated as Ive been trying to figure this out for the better part of a day.

image of predecessor map data after running the random_spanning_tree function:
[gdb watched variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaMJk.png)

[image]

Source:

```
struct VertexData
{
    int num;
    int pred;
    int dist;
};

struct EdgeData
{
    double dist;
};

typedef adjacency_matrix<undirectedS, VertexData, EdgeData > Graph;
typedef graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor Vertex;

Graph generateConnectedGraph2(int numVertices, double connectionProbability) {
    Graph graph(numVertices);
    std::random_device rand;
    random::minstd_rand gen(rand()); //Seeded Random number generator

    make_connected(graph);

    //build a minimally connected graph for the random spanning tree

    std::vector<double> xPos(num_vertices(graph));
    std::vector<double> yPos(num_vertices(graph));

    bool isPlanar = false;

    std::vector<Vertex> predecessor(numVertices);  // Predecessor map
    predecessor[0] = 0;  // Set the root vertex to 0
    // Generate random edges to create a connected graph
    random_spanning_tree(graph, gen, predecessor_map(make_iterator_property_map(predecessor.begin(), get(vertex_index, graph) )));
    
    printAdjMatrix(graph, numVertices);
    
    applyPredecessorMap(graph, predecessor);
    printAdjMatrix(graph, numVertices);
    
    // Iterate over each pair of vertices and potentially add an edge
    for (Vertex u = 0; u < numVertices; ++u) {
        for (Vertex v = u + 1; v < numVertices; ++v) {
            if (u != v && u != numVertices && !edge(u, v, graph).second && random::bernoulli_distribution<>(connectionProbability)(gen)) {
                add_edge(u, v, graph);
            }
        }
    }
    
    return graph;
}

void applyPredecessorMap(Graph& graph, const std::vector<Vertex>& predecessor) {
    int numVertices = num_vertices(graph);

    for (Vertex v = 1; v < numVertices; ++v) {
        Vertex u = predecessor[v];
        add_edge(u, v, graph);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working entirely as expected. The "large number" isn't random. It is the special value indicating that the first vertex has no predecessor:

```
assert(predecessor.at(vertex(0, graph)) == graph.null_vertex());
```

Meanwhile, you find a spanning tree, but it can, by definition, only consist of edges already in the graph, so `applyPredecessor` should not have an effect, unless you choose another graph model that allows duplicate edges.

Here's the code extended with a bit of output showing exactly how and that it all works:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ee47b65e544d1de)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/make_connected.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/random_spanning_tree.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <random>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
struct VertexData {
    int num;
    int pred;
    int dist;
};

struct EdgeData {
    double dist;
};

using Graph  = boost::adjacency_matrix<boost::undirectedS, VertexData, EdgeData>;
using Vertex = Graph::vertex_descriptor;

void applyPredecessorMap(Graph& graph, std::vector<Vertex> const& predecessor) {
    size_t numVertices = num_vertices(graph);

    for (Vertex v = 1; v < numVertices; ++v) {
        Vertex u = predecessor[v];
        add_edge(u, v, graph);
    }
}

Graph generateConnectedGraph2(size_t numVertices, double connectionProbability) {
    Graph graph(numVertices);
    std::random_device rand;
    std::minstd_rand gen(rand()); //Seeded Random number generator

    make_connected(graph);
    auto const original = graph;

    //build a minimally connected graph for the random spanning tree
    std::vector<double> xPos(num_vertices(graph));
    std::vector<double> yPos(num_vertices(graph));

    // bool isPlanar = false;

    std::vector<Vertex> predecessor(numVertices); // Predecessor map
    fmt::print("predecessor constructed: {}\n", predecessor);
    predecessor[0] = 0;                           // Set the root vertex to 0
    fmt::print("predecessor initialized: {}\n", predecessor);

    // Generate random edges to create a connected graph
    random_spanning_tree(
        std::as_const(graph), gen,
        predecessor_map(make_iterator_property_map(predecessor.begin(), get(boost::vertex_index, graph))));

    fmt::print("predecessor spanning: {}\n", predecessor);
    // v 0 doesn't have a predecessor
    assert(predecessor.at(vertex(0, graph)) == graph.null_vertex());

    print_graph(graph, std::cout << "Graph:\n");
    
    applyPredecessorMap(graph, predecessor);
    print_graph(graph, std::cout << "Graph with predecessors applied:\n");
    
    // Iterate over each pair of vertices and potentially add an edge
    std::bernoulli_distribution dist(connectionProbability);

    for (Vertex u = 0; u < numVertices; ++u) {
        for (Vertex v = u + 1; v < numVertices; ++v) {
            if (u != v && u != numVertices && !edge(u, v, graph).second && dist(gen)) {
                add_edge(u, v, graph);
            }
        }
    }

    print_graph(graph, std::cout << "Graph with random edges added:\n");

    return graph;
}

int main() {
    generateConnectedGraph2(10, 0.2);
}
```

Printing e.g.

```
predecessor constructed: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
predecessor initialized: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
predecessor spanning: [18446744073709551615, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
Graph:
0 <--> 1 
1 <--> 0 2 
2 <--> 1 3 
3 <--> 2 4 
4 <--> 3 5 
5 <--> 4 6 
6 <--> 5 7 
7 <--> 6 8 
8 <--> 7 9 
9 <--> 8 
Graph with predecessors applied:
0 <--> 1 
1 <--> 0 2 
2 <--> 1 3 
3 <--> 2 4 
4 <--> 3 5 
5 <--> 4 6 
6 <--> 5 7 
7 <--> 6 8 
8 <--> 7 9 
9 <--> 8 
Graph with random edges added:
0 <--> 1 6 9 
1 <--> 0 2 
2 <--> 1 3 6 
3 <--> 2 4 6 7 
4 <--> 3 5 8 
5 <--> 4 6 9 
6 <--> 0 2 3 5 7 
7 <--> 3 6 8 
8 <--> 4 7 9 
9 <--> 0 5 8
```

Or repeated runs:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for clarification! My biggest trouble so far has been figuring out how to use the library as I've found the documentation a little unclear for a newcomer. 
I took what you explained and changed the inputted graph to be a nearly wholly connected graph in order to create the random spanning tree I wanted. Earlier I had had this thought but assumed I went down the wrong road when a wholly connected graph caused the function to hardfault.  Thanks much for the help!